image upload in vercel deployment
I have written an action to a form in my project to upload an image to a local directory on the server. However the upload works in my local development server but not when I deploy to vercel. What could be the reason for this? I have tried changing the path several times...
await fs.writeFileSync(
        path.join(process.cwd(), `public/uploads/${imgName}.${file.ext}`),
        buffer
      );


I think I found out why it isn't uploading. It is because the images in the public directory are ment to be static and the directory does not exist at build time anymore. Is there another solution where to upload pictures to?
